# Spark Custom AccumulatorV2

Tags: apache-spark, accumulator

I have defined a Custom Accumulator as:

```
import org.apache.spark.util.LongAccumulator

class CustomAccumulator extends LongAccumulator with java.io.Serializable  {
  override def add(v: Long): Unit = {
    super.add(v)
    if (v % 100 == 0) println(v)
  }
}
```

And registered it as:

```
val cusAcc = new CustomAccumulator
sc.register(cusAcc, "customAccumulator")
```

My issue is that when I try to use it as:

```
val count = sc.customAccumulator
```

I get the following error:

```
<console>:51: error: value customAccumulator is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext
   val count = sc.customAccumulator
```

I am new to Spark and scala, and maybe missing something very trivial. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Spark API,
`AccumulatorV2` is no longer under package `org.apache.spark.SparkContext;` instead, it has been moved to `org.apache.spark.util`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Spark 2.0.0` you should use method `register` in `abstract class AccumulatorV2`:
`org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2#register`.

Something like this:

```
cusAcc.register(sc, scala.Option("customAccumulator"), false);
```